# Rotations correspondence to lie algebra

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Let $U,V$ be non-empty, proper, connected, open subsets of the sphere $S^D(1)$ of radius 1, centered about the origin in $\mathbb{R}^D$.  Is the subset $A$ of SO(D), defined by
$$
A \triangleq \left\{
R: \exists x\in U y \in V, Rx=y
\right\},
$$
an open subset of $SO(D)$ (of codimension $0$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $x\in U$, the orbit map $\rho_x:SO(D)\rightarrow S^D$ defined by $\rho_x(g)=g(x)$ is continuous, $A=\cup_{x\in U},\rho_x^{-1}(V)$ is open since $\rho_x^{-1}(V)$ is open. What is important here is the fact that $V$ is open, you maybe interested in the notion of compact open topology.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks and why the compact open topology?

Comment: Why does that show that the set if of codimension 0?

Comment: An open subset has codimension zero.

Comment: Oh....that makes sense since the topology is generated by open balls, each of which is of codimension 0.  OK cools! Thanks a ton Tsemo:)